# Looping through a list of objects within View and printing values with a single <%=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I'm looping through a list of objects using the following code within my `View`:

```
<% @myquiz.each do |x| %>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <%= x.quiz_ID %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This works fine, it prints the IDs on to the page.  However I feel that it would be cleaner if I didn't have to put so many sets of `<%`s and `<%=`s

The following would be preferable, but it doesn't work:

```
<% @myquiz.each do |x|

    render :text "<div>#{x.quiz_ID}</div>"

end %>
```

Is there a way to `put` information on to the screen within a loop like above, without having 3 sets of `<%` tags? and another <% tag for each subsequent value that I want to show on the page.

Comment: Sidenote: If you feel your code to be cleaner without all those HTML and ERB tags, [**Slim**](http://slim-lang.com/) might be for you. It's an excellent replacement for erb views.

Comment: Please see the update.  I've realised that doing this in one line of code isn't helpful, because I want to wrap some HTML around it too

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wish to loop around my objects and concatenate a string of HTML with various values from my object within it.  Without having 3 sets of <% %> tags

Comment: Use some other templating language if you want to avoid <% %>. Just don't put this much ruby stuff into your view just to avoid the brackets. Take a look at slim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few hints, merely to give a few pointers on Ruby methods.

```
# Original
<%= @myquiz.each do |x|
    puts "<div>" . x.quiz_ID . "</div>"
end %>
```

`<%= expression %>` will cause the expression to be visible in the HTML. Thus you'll have to manipulate the return value of your expression. You're using `.each` there, while for this purpose **`.map`** is more suitable, as it will return an array with the output of the block for each input variable.

In the block the last statement is the **return value**, no need to print stuff someway.

In the end, an array like `['A', 'B', 'C']` will still want to be joined by some line breaks stuff, so the expression would need to be joined with **`.join('<br />')`.**

This is a hell of a mess, but anyway, here it is:

```
<%= @myquiz.map {|x| "<div>#{ x.quiz_id }</div>" }.join("<br />").html_safe %>

# or

<%= @myquiz.map(&:quiz_id).map { |id| "<div>#{ id }</div>" }.join("<br />").html_safe %>
```

**Don't do this at home. Seriously. Just note how .map works, how it collects return values (the last statement), and how to join array elements to form a string.**

*Further options:*

What would DHH do? 
Presumably go with the extra brackets, or move the logic somewhere else (into a helper or decorator) and just output some kind of `<%= quiz_results %>`.

What would I do?
Take a look at [**Slim**](http://slim-lang.com/) and `slim-rails` for integrating it and auto-generating `.html.slim` views.

```
# In a slim view
- @quizzes.each do |quiz|
  div = quiz.id
```

Comment: Great, I understand this a bit more now.  So can you provide the way that the Gods would achieve it?  Also, with this example it appears angle brackets are being outputted as `&lt;` rather than actual html :(

Comment: Added some hints. Maybe by marking the string as `.html_safe` it will be output the way you like.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for your help :).  I hate being such a noob to a programming language.  aghh.

Comment: Everybody starts small. And for everyone there's way to go, so: Enjoy the journey!

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= @myquiz.map(&:quiz_ID).join(', ') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

do block with curry brackets

```
<%= @myquiz.each { |x| puts x.quiz_ID } =%>
```

if statement in block has more than 2 
you should write block with 'do-end', that's right.

Comment: puts writes to `$stdout`, thats not helping here.

Comment: Thanks.  It's nice to know that I can do it one string, but how would I go about wrapping some HTML around it? Please see my update to the question :)